# Binding to knockoutjs a dynamically created fabricjs itext

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, fabricjs

I have a fabricjs canvas that I am trying to use knockoutjs to manage states for text objects. There is a button  when clicked it adds a new IText to the canvas...

But I also have a button

Trying to make the button be associated to the new IText so when the user clicks the button it only makes that IText bold... And I am trying to do this using knockout... 
So when the text is bold the button state changes to show what state the text is in...

Cant figure out how to associate knockout to the IText since there is no html element... how do i do this in JS?

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/G6MGm/) shows a way to do it.. but its not a dynamically created object

```
<canvas id="c" data-bind="fabric: [ { type: 'Rect', params: rect.getParams }, { type: 'Rect', params: rect2.getParams } ]"></canvas>
```

Thanks for help... I have made a jsfiddle here for your convenience

https://jsfiddle.net/sarin/62ku4kyj/

Answer (score 0):

You must create an computed observable of any name, and then in the function for the computed observable:  1. reference the observable (e.g. myStyle) and 2. create the code to call the fabric interface.

```
myScratchVar = ko.computed(function() {
  var scratchStyle = self.myStyle();   // triggers this function to run
  MyFunctionToSetFabricAttributes(scratchStyle);  
  return true;   
});
```

Comment: Sorry I am knew to knockout, cant seem to get this working, anyway you can show show me on this jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/sarin/62ku4kyj/

Comment: First, you must decide what you want to keep track of ... what do you want in the view model, as far as observables?   Maybe you don't need Knockout, since Fabric has a JSON utility (?)

Comment: I just want to manage states, so when the user select a text, bold ,italics buttons the buttons should switch states to match the text, eg: if its a bold text the button state should change to bold, manages those states gets crazy... knockout seems to be great for managing states...

Comment: So, this is not so straightforward, since Knockout observables are functions, and are set by calling them.   In this case, you can use the Fabric callback functions, such as  "object:selected" to run a function that determines  the properties of that object and set the style of the buttons as needed. see [link](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#serialization)